# Почему не пускает по ssh ключу?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Настроил авторизацию по ssh.

Сгенерировал ключи. Добавил открытый ключ в authorized_keys. Рестанул ssh

И теперь он пускает по ssh ключу только если я залогинен по паролю.

В sshd_config авторизация по ssh2 включена
Вот что пишет в логах

> Feb 26 18:41:28 vm-10cac6d0 sshd[10970]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xx.xx.xx user=root
>   Feb 26 18:41:28 vm-10cac6d0 sshd[10970]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
>   Feb 26 18:41:31 vm-10cac6d0 sshd[10974]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xx.xx.xx user=root
>   Feb 26 18:41:33 vm-10cac6d0 sshd[10974]: Failed password for root from xx.xx.xx port 45392 ssh2

sshd_config

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

UPD:

Не имею linux, генерировал на putty, можно конечно поставить виртуалку и там сделать.

Что я делал:

1) создал через putty ключи (пароль добавлял)
2) залил открытый ключ на хост 
3) cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
4) удалил открытый ключ и рестанул ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вы делали в целом, а последовательность действий должна быть такой:

На хосте, с которого хотим подключаться по ssh на другой хост без пароля, выполняем команду `ssh-keygen`, пароль для ключа указывать не будем:

```
 [user-name@linux]# ssh-keygen
  Generating public/private rsa key pair.
  Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user-name/.ssh/id_rsa):
  Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
  Enter same passphrase again:
  Your identification has been saved in /home/user-name/.ssh/id_rsa.
  Your public key has been saved in /home/user-name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
  The key fingerprint is:
  f3:d5:db:e5:d9:eb:ce:d5:cc:48:a3:b4:cb:73:a4:ef user-name@linux
  The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|             .   |
|        S   o + .|
|         o o +.O=|
|          . ooo.O|
|           .o.o o|
|            o=E= |
+-----------------+
```

Копируем pub на целевой хост, юзеру, под которым хотим ходить без пароля (в этой операции пароль надо будет ввести один раз для копирования):

```
[user-name@linux .ssh]# ssh-copy-id another-user@host-name-or-ip
another-user@host-name-or-ip's password: 
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'another-user@host-name-or-ip'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

Заходим на целевой хост без пароля:

```
[user-name@linux]# ssh another-user@host-name-or-ip
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

36 packages can be updated.
11 updates are security updates.
```

Никаких рестартов sshd (для sshd из коробки) не требуется.

**Update**

Вариант для Windows (putty.exe и puttygen.exe)

Как и ранее - генерируем пару public/private с помощью puttygen.exe (и паролем для ключа - опционально).

Поскольку этот процесс происходит в gui и требует болтания мышкой по экрану, то описывать тут особо нечего.

Предполагаем, что процесс генерации завершен успешно и по итогу у нас есть `Public key`, который сразу можно скопировать из окна (поле `Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file:`) и вставить в целевой сервер (файл authorized_keys для требуемого юзера). А приватный ключ сохраняем в файл (например, host_name.ppk)

Далее запускаем putty.exe и делаем настройки сессии, понадобится:

- имя или ip целевого хоста
- имя нужного пользователя (это в разделе Connection -> Data -> Auto-login username)
- и приватный ключ. Его надо добавить в разделе Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> Private key file for authentication. Сюда вставляем файл host_name.ppk.

Cохраняем эту сессию, и коннектимся к серверу.

Если на ключ был установлен пароль, то будет предложено его ввести.

Если ключ без пароля, то появится приглашение оболочки сервера.

Comment: Не имею linux, генерировал на putty, можно конечно поставить виртуалку и там сделать.
Что я делал:
1) создал через putty ключи (пароль добавлял)
2) залил открытый ключ на хост
3) cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
4) удалил открытый ключ и рестанул ssh

Comment: @Drop вы это в вопрос напишите, т.к. данная инфа частично меняет решение

Comment: @Drop добавил в update для windows.

Comment: Да, спасибо!
Вопрос, я коннектился через filezilla с ключом но пароль не запрашивался, это норма?

Comment: @Drop скажем так, такой тип соединения требует указания клиенту приватного ключа. Если клиент (putty, winscp, filezilla, etc) умеют работать с таким типом соединения, то все получится, если не умеют, то сами понимаете. Про filezilla, к сожалению, ничего не знаю.

Comment: Да вроде умеет)
http://prntscr.com/ikas0e

Comment: @Drop ради интереса попробовал сейчас с filezilla - все нормально, спрашивает пароль от ключа, после чего отображает директорию сервера.

Comment: @Drop, *можно конечно поставить виртуалку и там сделать* — не имеет значения, где вы сгенерируете пару файлов с публичным и секретным ключами. если вы к серверу подключетесь, используя пароль, то и там можно сгенерировать, после чего скопировать файлы на локальную машину.

Comment: @defrag 
Вот что было у меня http://prntscr.com/ikbasm

Comment: @Drop хм. Ну тут либо sshd не запущен, либо что-то с фаерволом, либо что-то с несовместимостью шифров клиент-сервер, хотя тут рубануло бы соединение сразу. В логах сервера есть что-нибудь?